# JQuery table search number of rows by multiple contains value

Tags: jquery, pseudo-class

i would like to search in a table the number of rows by multiple :contains() value of td.

```
<table id="tabCity">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>City</td></tr>
<tr><td>Paul</td><td color>Smith</td><td>Boston</td></tr>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>Smith</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td>Smith</td><td>Green</td><td>Boston</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nick</td><td>Smith</td><td>Boston</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<button class="go">Search Surname Smith in Boston</button>
<br>
<label>The result must be 2</label>

$(document).on('click', '.go', function(){
var rows= $("#tabCity tr td:nth-child(2):contains('Smith'), td:nth-child(3):contains('Boston')");
alert(rows.length);
});
```

Look here:  http://jsfiddle.net/drh0mvhz/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter()` allows you to do more complex filtering:

```
var rows = $("#tabCity tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("td:nth-child(2):contains('Smith')").length 
        && $(this).find("td:nth-child(3):contains('Boston')").length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bh6t6tf6/

Comment: Good idea... but don't work for me... in effect i use Datatable( https://datatables.net/ ) and i use fnGetNodes ( https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetNodes ), so my problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/drh0mvhz/10/